# Как в xml в LinearLayout добавить другой layout который уже создан в папке res/layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Как в `xml` в `LinearLayout` добавить другой `layout`, который уже создан в папке `res/layout` ?

К примеру готовый `layout` называется `game_field.xml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем случае на помощь спешит тег `<include/>`

Пример

```
<include layout="@layout/game_field"/>
```

Немного подробнее [в оффициальном тренинге](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)